# How to show same swagger-editor twice on the same page in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I want to implement the swagger-editor from npm swagger-editor-dist two times on the same html in Angular 6+. I have displayed swagger-editor on expand button in a modal and also below the expand button. However, it displays swagger only in the expanded modal and not in the div below it.

How can I display the same Swagger both the times?

**Front -page ui-**

[image: UI]

**Swagger in Modal -**

[image: swagger in modal]

code -

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">

<i class="fa fa-expand" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">

</i>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Swagger of </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

<div class="col-12">
<div id="swagger-editorInbox"  style="height:500px">
</div>
</div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row"  style="border:solid 1px gray">

<div id="swagger-editorInbox"  style="height:500px"></div>
</div>



</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
declare const SwaggerEditorBundle: any

export class swaggerComponent implements OnInit{


editorInbox :any

ngOnInit(){

this.editorInbox = SwaggerEditorBundle({
dom_id: "#swagger_editorInbox"
})

mySwagger = '....//my swagger// ...';

this.editorInbox.specActions.updateSpec(mySwagger);


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 ids. you may need to do `styling`. very hard to do styling. I will recommend show only one at a time. `Toggle` content only

**Id:**

```
<div id="swagger_editorInbox1"  style="height:500px"></div>
</div>

<div id="swagger_editorInbox2"   style="height:500px"></div>
</div>
```

**//JS**

```
this.editorInbox = SwaggerEditorBundle({
dom_id: "#swagger_editorInbox1"
})

this.editorInbox = SwaggerEditorBundle({
dom_id: "#swagger_editorInbox2"
})
```

Comment: Sorry ...doesn't work. Getting error -ERROR Invariant Violation : Minified  React Error #37; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=37  for full message ....

Comment: Create 2 different Id

Comment: I checked there sample, It works only with ID i guess. So you need to create 2 ids. i updated sample.

Comment: You have suggested a good option to toggle the content. I am trying to do that

Comment: yes, i also did same in my project. Just change the swagger URL and reload.

Comment: I tried to use *ngIf="showSwaggerModal" for modal  and ngIf="!showSwaggerModal" for the second div ...but still get the same error - ERROR Invariant Violation : Minified React Error #37; visit facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=37 for full message ....  . Can you please help

Comment: I guess *ngIf doesn't work on swagger-editor. What is the method that you have used? can you please share ?

Comment: Haha! nice :-) Enjoy! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">

<i class="fa fa-expand" (click)="showSwaggerModalFunction(); showSwaggerModal= 'true'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">

</i>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Swagger of </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"   [hidden]="showSwaggerModal !== 'true'">

<div class="col-12">
<div id="swagger-editorInboxDummy"  style="height:500px">
</div>
</div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button"  (click)="onSaveModal()" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row"  style="border:solid 1px gray">

<div id="swagger-editorInbox"  style="height:500px"></div>
</div>



</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
showSwaggerModal : string = 'false'


showSwaggerModalFunction(){


this.showSwaggerModal = 'true';

var editorInboxDummy = SwaggerEditorBundle({
dom_id : "#swagger-editorInboxDummy"
})

editorInboxDummy.specActions.updateSpec(mySwagger)
}

onSaveModal(){

this.showSwaggerModal = 'false';
}
```